# I want to add selected listview item in searchbox horizontally ?Is it possible in android?

Tags: android

[I want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpC6b.jpg)

[currently i am getting this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdHKE.png)

```
Please help if this is possible.thanks in advance.
```

Comment: is it possible please let me know its urgent..upon click text please see the image

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You can create a custom view or you can look for github project for this kind of view.